# Will newer versions of an app have the same GUID?

Tags: version, guid, updates, uuid

The specific software I'm interested in are the drivers for Athena, Gemalto, Oberthur and SafeNet security tokens, but I also want to know if there's a rule regarding GUID change in app versions. I use Windows Management Instrumentation Command (WMIC) to get *{3A7F6F75-5A23-4C35-BE3C-D84F6EE8117C}* as GUID and *3.3.3* as version for *Oberthur Technologies ID-One Token driver*, for instance. Now, I will make inquiries to *my server* for this software based on its GUID and check for *newer versions*. Is that ok or **can newer versions have different GUIDs?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUID usually don't change when version change. As long as you keep the same interfaces GUID stay the same. 
 But Sometimes company decide to change GUID to make clear distinction between 2 versions, or to give an easy possibility to have old and new version at the same time.

Comment: So the GUID can change. Is it safe to assume that the product name will be the same, at least? Which fields / parts of an app remain unchanged across different versions?

Comment: Sometimes GUID change most of the times for technical reasons. But GUID used to be more trustful that product name or company name. Because rebranding and acquisition are very common. I'd GUID change from version in the same company and GUID stay the same for years even after acquisition.